# Patching React Native with patch-package not working

Tags: react-native, node-modules, patch-package

I'm trying to fix an issue in React Native, I forked [the RN repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native), added some code to some java files, and run the [rn-tester App](https://github.com/facebook/react-native), my fix was working fine on the rn-tester App, but when adding this fix to a `react-native` package inside `node_modules` directory and patching it using `patch-package`, my fix not working even if I deleted the `node_modules` and installed them again, I see my code inside `react-native` java files but it have no effect on the App.

Also, any `Log.d` or `System.out.println` messages appear on the rn-tester App but don't appear on the other App.

- added some code to `/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/.../somefiles.java`  that fixed an RN issue on the [rn-tester App.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native)
- run `npx patch-package react-native` and inside `package.json` file under scripts added  `"postinstall": "npx patch-package"` .
- deleted `node_modules` and run `npm i` .
- checked `/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/.../somefiles.java` and my code existed.
- run `npm run android` .
- The RN issue still exists.

**Expected**

The code fixed the issue on the `rn-tester App` so it should fix it on the other App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Rect Native takes its Java dependency as an AAR archive any changes to node modules will be skipped. You need to build react native from source as described here: https://reactnative.dev/contributing/how-to-build-from-source